# Monitor cloning with Windows 10 and different refresh rates uses wrong refresh rate

Tags: windows-10, refresh-rate

Cloning a 144Hz monitor to a 60Hz monitor is behaving strangely on Windows 10.

The display output to the 144Hz monitor is confirmed to be 144Hz, however applications on the 144Hz monitor are only updated at 60Hz, except for the mouse cursor movements and fullscreen directx 9 games.

A second 144Hz display which is not cloned to a 60Hz display behaves normally.

[image: Display Layout Screenshot]

1. 144Hz 1920x1080 DisplayPort
2. 60Hz 1920x1080 HDMI (capture card, clone of display 1)
3. 144Hz 1920x1080 DVI dual-link (extended display)

The issue appears to be related to DWM. Stopping DWM using [DisableDWM](http://www.overclock.net/t/1441921/windows-8-1-no-dwm-aka-aero-aka-desktop-composition#post_23127532) causes non-fullscreen applications to update at 144Hz properly, but breaks the taskbar and other parts of Windows 10 so is not useful.

Fullscreen OpenGL applications update at 60FPS even when DWM is stopped.

It seems that anything which uses VSYNC is synced at 60Hz instead of 144Hz. As DWM uses VSYNC, it syncs to 60Hz. However stopping DWM doesn't fix everything, as other applications which sync to the monitor framerate (such as Chrome), [continue to sync at 60Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPRAL.png).

[DxDiag Report](https://gist.github.com/nallar/4f8c480f9a89ae071c077a42d150e376)
[Nvidia System Information Report](https://gist.github.com/nallar/83b9ef57a047f929eb08f55481cda476)

Comment: http://aka.ms/Fi26tm <-- Windows 10 feedback hub report of this bug

Comment: If you are cloning just to send audio to an AV receiver, you can edit the EDID to 144 Hz. The AVR will still decode the audio even though the video signal is out of range.